# Raspbian detect keyboard input while sleeping

Tags: python, keyboard, sleep, raspbian, detection

I have a python script in Raspbian that loops indefinitely and sleeps for 15 minutes between the main function executions. Main is threaded but usually takes 3 seconds to run. I don't want any code to interrupt, when in time, the next call is made. During sleep I would like to detect keypress 'r' to optionally start another func, possibly threaded as well.

I tried the pynput module but got weird pauses that seem to be related to threading and checking in with VNC, that I need. I also tried regular old input inside a thread but couldn't get the thread to end without user input.

The keyboard module works great in Windows but detects no keys for Raspbian. I am running the script using sudo "sudo python3 scriptname.py" I don't really care if the key detection is instant by using threads. I can chop up my sleep cycle to call the function after a minute or so if needed. I just can't have a big pause.

```
import time
import keyboard
import threading

def mainFunc():
    print('does stuff')

def keyFunc():
    print('do key detect stuff')

while True:
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=mainFunc)
    t1.start()
    time.sleep(60)
    t1.join()
    keyboard.on_press_key("r", lambda _:keyFunc())
    for _ in range(14):
        time.sleep(60)
    keyboard.unhook_all()
```

Comment: Looks like I might solve it with letting a daemon thread with regular old input run in its own loop outside the main loop and just be careful not to use it at times when mainFunc runs. Hopefully it is stable over a long time period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def inputDaemon():
    while True:
        x = input('r to reload')
        if x == 'r': doTheFunc()

inpD = threading.Thread(target=inputDaemon)
inpD.daemon = True
inpD.start()
```

What I eventually used and it's been working fine.

Answer (score 0):

One way I think that could help is to create a timespan duration from a datetime object and utilize this for your main loop.

Here is an example I created. Hope it is helpful for your pi raspbian script.

```
from datetime import *
import time
import keyboard
import threading

#every 3 second function
x_start = datetime.now()
xSleep=3
def mainFunc():
    newTime = datetime.now()
    if(getTimeDiff(x_start,newTime)>xSleep):
        setXStart(datetime.now())
        return True
#every 15 minute function
y_start = datetime.now()
ySleep=900
def fifteenMinuteFunction():
    newTime = datetime.now()
    if(getTimeDiff(y_start,newTime)>ySleep):
        setYStart(datetime.now())
        return True 
#key press function (from pressing p)
def keyFunc():
    print("do keystuff")
#calculate time difference since last call
def getTimeDiff(start, end):
    span = end - start
    #convert to string
    spanStr = str(span)[0:7]
    hours   = spanStr[0:1]
    minutes = spanStr[2:4]
    seconds = spanStr[5:7]
    #convert to rounded int (seconds)
    seconds = int(seconds) + (int(minutes) * 60) + (int(hours) * 60 * 60)
    return int(seconds)
#set new start time for 3 second function
def setXStart(newTime):
    global x_start 
    x_start = newTime
#set new start tiem for 15 minute function
def setYStart(newTime):
    global y_start 
    y_start = newTime

#bind keyboard keys
keyboard.on_press_key("p", lambda _:keyFunc())                  # p do stuff function

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('x'):                                # exit keybind to x
        exit()
    elif mainFunc():
        print("Doing thingy every "+str(xSleep)+" seconds")     # 3 seconds
    elif fifteenMinuteFunction():
        print("Doing thingy every "+str(ySleep)+" seconds")     # 15 mins
    else:
        time.sleep(.1)
```

Output:

```
do keystuff
doing thingy every 3 seconds
do keystuff
doing thingy every 3 seconds
doing thingy every 3 seconds
....
doing thingy every 900 seconds
...
```